# C# Hashset Contains Non-Unique Objects

Tags: c#, hashset

Using this class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string c1, c2;

    public Foo(string one, string two)
    {
        c1 = one;
        c2 = two;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (c1 + c2).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And this HashSet

```
HashSet<Foo> aFoos = new HashSet<Foo>();
Foo aFoo = new Foo("a", "b");

aFoos.Add(aFoo);
aFoos.Add(new Foo("a", "b"));

label1.Text = aFoos.Count().ToString();
```

I get the answer 2, when surely it should be 1. Is there a way to fix this so my HashSet contains only unique objects?

Thanks, Ash.

Comment: You haven't overridden `Equals`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `HashSet<T>` type ultamitely uses equality to determine whether 2 objects are equal or not.  In the type `Foo` you have only overridden `GetHashCode` and not equality.  This means equality checks will default back to `Object.Equals` which uses reference equality.  This explains why you see multiple items in the `HashSet<Foo>`.

To fix this you will need to override `Equals` in the `Foo` type.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
  var other = obj as Foo;
  if (other == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return c1 == other.c1 && c2 == other.c2;
}
```

Comment: +1 because it is correct, but one may add that the hashes returned by `GetHashCode` are allowed to collide for different values, which is why comparing the hash code does not ensure the equality of objects in general.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override `Equals` method. Only `GetHashCode` is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the equals method as well. The reason for this is that the hashcode is allowed to collide for two objects that is not equal. Otherwise it won't work.

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{ 
   Foo otherObject = obj as Foo;
   return otherObject != null && otherObject.c1 == this.c1 && otherObject.c2 == this.c2;
}
```

Comment: The expression `local.Equals(null)` should return `false` not `true`

Comment: True, just wrote it to fast for myself :).